# Advanced matching in duplicates

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I need to compare some cells in my table but I need to select more columns so its little bit tricky. Here is my table:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SDiGR5Jy58LEN0AfTWElAi6UhSFnvzuQESc0VF7Xycs/edit?usp=sharing

I need to check if in columns E, G, J, L, O, Q, T, V some number matches number in column A. If yes, then highlight that number in A column with red number.

I tried to create formula with conditional formatting but this not works.

I will be happy for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Please select A26:B124 and apply a Custom formula is of:

```
=countif(E:E,$A26)+countif(G:G,$A26)
```

with the addition of further `countif`s to suit you and your choice of formatting.

[COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)